# How encapsulation all dll file in Setup file using install shield

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, setup-project

I developed c# win form and use Devexpress 
now i need to create setup project, but i don't now how to involved Devexpress dll files in setup file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use our [Assembly Deployment Tool](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AssemblyDeploymentTool/CustomDocument17237), which is shipped along with our components to get assemblies that are necessary for your application.

After that you can add these required assemblies in the setup project. Go through InstallShied documentation to add output as we do in Visual Studio Setup project. Refer below documentation, It may help you do as you want in your setup project..

[How to deploy WinForms applications on client machines](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A4)
[How to distribute applications that use DevExpress .NET Windows Forms controls](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A240)
[InstallShield: Filtering output files](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/620015/InstallShield-Filtering-output-files)